# WebLogic on Virtual Machine/Eclipse Runtime Environment

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, weblogic

I have a virtual machine that I successfully installed WebLogic on. My idea is to create a Dynamic Web application in Eclipse, export it to a .war file and transfer it to the virtual machine(Win. Server 2019) that is running WebLogic. The problem I have encountered is that because of the fact I don't have WebLogic on my host, I can't create a runtime environment in Eclipse for it. If I have a runtime environment that isn't WebLogic will it matter if I'm simply converting it to a .war file? Or should I not be lazy and download and configure WebLogic on my host.

P.S. My application connects to a MySQL database, will it be able to access that database when moved over to the Windows Server 2019 virtual machine in Virtual Box.

Comment: WebLogic Server is not required to build a war file with Eclipse. You can just export your project as a war file and deploy it in your VM.

Comment: Thank you for your response Emmanuel, ok that's good to know. So no matter what runtime environment I chose in the initial setup in Eclipse, my virtual WebLogic server will successfully run the .war that I export it as?

Comment: Yes. War file are part of the J2EE specifications. The only point you need to address is the deployment descriptor weblogic.xml which is specific to WebLogic.

Comment: Is there a way to create this in Eclipse? Or should I find an XML editor to make this

Comment: you can write any xml file with Eclipse

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to use WebLogic for this?  If you're building a conventional war-file based application, it's much more effective to just use Tomcat for this, which you would have no trouble running on your host.

Comment: No, it doen't have to be. I guess I was more along the lines of curious as to if it will run despite not selecting the runtime environment as WebLogic. I'm new to making web projects with Java, but I had already had a working instance of WebLogic on a VM and wanted to know if it would be a hastle making it work after converting it to a .war file